Set the number of colours in an LMDE6, 64Bit, with Cinnamon Desktop, which is based on debian 12
inxi -Fxz
System:
...

  Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics vendor: Dell
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-7.5 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: crocus gpu: i915
    resolution: 1600x900~60Hz
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 22.3.6 renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW
    GT2) direct-render: Yes
...

Under Linux it is common that you can set the number of colours that an AMD or NVidia graphics card or the GPU unit of the CPU should display with the driver of the graphics card.
But how do you set the number of colours under a Debian 12 Linux such as LMDE6 if you are using an Intel CPU with its own GPU?
According to some internet sources, the number of colours can be set with the following command line:
xrandr --output <MonitorName> --setcolor 24bit

However, this seems to be a misconception that such functionality is offered by xrandr.
Starting points for alternative solutions:

Query the graphics type used: lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

Use an icc.icm color profile file and possibly adjust the number of
colors by changing this file.

Modification of the data read out by
the system from the display used, which can be decoded with DMI
Decode: sudo hwinfo -monitor and sudo dmidecode

Change a file
such as /etc/X11/xorg.conf or /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ , neither of
which appear to be present in LMDE6 or looks like dont have the
follow section. But perhaps about like the follow in a other located
file:
Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    DefaultDepth    16bit
EndSection



Remark:
Its looks for me, Xorg are used bei LMDE6:
No Wayland service looks running on LMDE6, but the well known Xorg service are running.
"Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) 6 does not use Wayland as its default display server protocol. Instead, it uses Xorg, which is the traditional choice for Linux desktop environments. The discussion in the Linux Mint forums indicates that while work has begun on integrating Wayland support into Cinnamon, the default desktop environment for Linux Mint, it is not expected to replace Xorg as the default display server anytime soon. The goal is to have a functional Wayland session by around 2026, but until then, Xorg remains the primary choice for LMDE 6 users."
Source:
https://www.phind.com/search?cache=he0i94eo7k5352vhtuggrz20

Do try the 4th option. The fact that those xorg.conf do not exist does not prevent you from creating them.

The problem is, you seem to be using Wayland and xrandr is just talking to the Xwayland server...

Perhaps, the follow source can give a hint for a non wayland solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1557/how-to-change-the-color-depth

As pointed out in comments, your problem has got nothing to do with the GPU being used but with the fact that, as you reported your system (more precisely your window-manager) is using Wayland as a backend.

Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9
driver: X:
loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: crocus gpu: i915
resolution: 1600x900~60Hz

Support for xrandr on systems running Wayland-compositors is close to inexistent if not using the -force-xrandr-emulation option.
Some DEs do offer the possibility to set the color depth via some system settings gui or environment variables :

KDE-Plasma5 : setting KWIN_DRM_PREFER_COLOR_DEPTH=24 into /etc/environment

If yours does not then, you might have to consider xrandr replacements such as kanshi, nwg-displays, wallutils, wdisplays or wlr-randr

Good Starting points for a solution. kanshi , wdisplays and wlr-randr ofered by LMDE6 software center. Which DEs do offer the possibility to set the color depth via some system settings gui.

A KDE-Plasma5 Desktop looks unknown for me on a Debian 12 based LMDE6 system. A folder "/etc/environment" dont exist on checked system, but a /etc/environment.d folder, if its comparable. But its unknown which file on this folder need o edit for a Cinnamon Desktop.

@Alfred.37 : Do you get some mean to select the options used when launching your wayland-compositor (in particular the-force-xrandr-emulation) and BTW what is it ? If you don't know, what is your DE ? Cinnamon ?

I dont now what you mean by "Is there a way to select the options used when starting the Wayland compositor (specifically the-force-xrandr-emulation), and what is it by the way ? If you don't know, what is your DE ?" But I cann tell you wh<t Cinnamon mean: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)

@Alfred.37 : OK then please post the output of ps -efl launched as root on whatever terminal.

the desktop envirement is: Cinnamon, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment) Thats the standard on LMDE6.

@Alfred.37 : OK then but what sounds definitely not standard to me is having wayland as backend. On 2024 eve, support was alpha level and stable forecast to 2026. My opinion is then that you are running something at best experimental with all the possible annoyances that come with. Do you remember having had some choice when installing ?

"Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) 6 does not use Wayland as its default display server protocol. Instead, it uses Xorg, which is the traditional choice for Linux desktop environments. The discussion in the Linux Mint forums indicates that while work has begun on integrating Wayland support into Cinnamon, the default desktop environment for Linux Mint, it is not expected to replace Xorg as the default display server anytime soon. The goal is to have a functional Wayland session by around 2026, but until then, Xorg remains the primary choice for LMDE 6 users." Source: www.phind.com
